# A quantity that distinguishes finer than Hausdorff dimension

Tags: reference-request, measure-theory, dimension-theory, hausdorff-dimension

Consider sets $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ with Lebesgue measure zero and Hausdorff dimension one. For instance  the set of real numbers with bounded entries in their  continued fraction expansion have this property. Using iterated function systems it is easy to construct further examples.

I wonder I there is a quantity that  distinguishes the "size" of such sets.  The quantity should be a least monotone with respect to inclusion and stable with respect to unions.

Comment: I think such a quantity should moreorless characterize the shape of a set, where by shape I mean what remains invariant while performing a similitude of some ambient space.

Comment: But I doubt one can reach such a fine description through a single real number, maybe it would be necessary to define some kind of "scale-dependent" metric/curvature, hence generalizing Riemann ideas to much broader contexts.

Comment: It would be interesting to see your example in more detail. For Brownian motion a similar issue happened and there we used a generalized Hausdorff dimension but with a gauge function that captures the dynamics. For many useful geometric measure theory results cf Mattila's geometry of sets and measures. For generalized H.dimension see chapter 4.

Comment: One can of course refine the scale of (Hausdorff) measures by using scaling functions such as $h(t) = t(\log t)^{\alpha}$ etc. instead of $h(t)=t^{\alpha}$.

Comment: And continue to refine ... $t \log(1/t)^\alpha\log\log(1/t)^\beta$

Comment: And more generally assigning a vector  $ (\alpha_{i})_{i\geq 0} $ so that  $ h(t)=\prod_{i}(\log_{i}(t))^{\alpha_{i}} $ with  $ \alpha_{i} $ vanishing for all but finitely many  $ i $ .

Comment: The most obvious thing to me would be to simply affix, as appropriate, additional smallness descriptions to "measure zero" that still allow for Hausdorff dimension $1$ (e.g. being topologically closed, being first Baire category, being $\sigma$-porous or even porous in various ways, etc. along with combinations, such as being closed AND porous, etc.) and additional largeness conditions to "Hausdorff dimension $1$" that still allow for measure zero (such as second Baire category, complement of first category, non-porous, etc.). Of course, this doesn't give exactly what you're asking for . . .